# While LEDs on GPIO2 work OK, but on the GPIO1 with LPC1768

Tags: c, embedded, gpio, nxp-microcontroller, lpc

I have a custom board with device LPC1768. While every other functionalities (such as LCD on SPI, Ethernet, I2C EEPROM, etc.) are OK,
for some reason, while I can turn ON and OFF LEDs on the GPIO2 but I can't do the same for the pins on the GPIO1. Maybe I shouldn't blame whole GPIO1 (or myself) but at least the part I try to use.

If I connect a button on one of the the GPIO1 pins (with internal pull-ups and as an OUTPUT)
I can read the button inputs as it should be.

Here is the definition part as per the [user manual](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi_yb25yIzwAhVmMewKHXzMDjYQFjAAegQIBBAF&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nxp.com%2Fdocs%2Fen%2Fuser-guide%2FUM10360.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1plU1XiIPQrGyl1Ed5SYZV);

```
#define FIO_BASE_ADDR       (0x2009C000)
#define FIO1CLR             (*(volatile unsigned int  *)(FIO_BASE_ADDR + 0x3C))
#define FIO2CLR             (*(volatile unsigned int  *)(FIO_BASE_ADDR + 0x5C))
#define FIO1SET             (*(volatile unsigned int  *)(FIO_BASE_ADDR + 0x38))
#define FIO2SET             (*(volatile unsigned int  *)(FIO_BASE_ADDR + 0x58))
```

While a LED on the pin P2.5 turns ON and OFF as it should be;

```
FIO2SET = (1uL << 5); // P2.5
FIO2CLR = (1uL << 5); // P2.5
```

A LED on P1.18 doesn't turn ON;

```
FIO1SET = (1uL << 18); // P1.18
```

In order to test all the LEDs connected to the GPIO1 pins, I wrote two lines of code using [`LPC17xx.h`](https://www.keil.com/dd/docs/arm/nxp/lpc17xx/lpc17xx.h) and then proofed that it works, all the LEDs are turning ON and OFF accordingly.

```
LPC_GPIO1->FIOSET = 0xffffffff;
LPC_GPIO1->FIOCLR = 0xffffffff;
```

Any input highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you verify hat your `FIO1SET` points to same address as `LPC_GPIO1->FIOSET`? You might also use different values than `0xffffffff` to see which bit is really controlling your LED.

Comment: Sounds like the typical pin routing nightmare. Check out the PINSEL3 register.

Comment: Thanks Gerhardh and Lundin. I checked that registers. But, it wasn't about it. I have then wanted to test what if I remove button initialization routines because they were on the same GPIO1. And then LEDs have started to work (ON and OFF)! 
And then now I have other question for you. This line does something and effect LED pins: `FIO1DIR &= (1uL << 25); //P1.25`. If I comment that line, then buttons are also working next to the LEDs (I think the default DIR is set as OUTPUT). Do you see an issue `FIO1DIR` of buttons and `FIO1DIR` of LEDs? Their pins are different after all.

Comment: All pins driving something should be set as outputs. Even if you sink current through the port by pulling it low ("active low"). So the corresponding data direction register should always be set. In case of buttons you would have it as inputs though, and pull resistors are necessary - internal or external.

Comment: Btw ensure that the pin can actually drive a LED by looking up electrical characteristics. Some MCUs can source/sink some 20mA, others can't. Others yet are better at sourcing or sinking. Others yet have dedicated pins for driving things directly. If the pin can't deliver enough current, then nothing will work and you need to add an external buffer/BJT/MOSFET/op amp etc.

Comment: @Lundin. I am aware all what you say. While this didn't work `FIO1DIR &= (1uL << 25); //P1.25` but this worked `FIO1DIR &= ~((1uL << BUTTON1_BIT)) ;`. And I have no worry about source/sink particularly for the LEDs. I am driving them via mosfets anyway. Thanks a lot for your inputs.

Comment: `FIO1DIR &= (1uL << 25);` is essentially the same as `FIO1DIR = (1uL << 25); // only this pin is output`. But `FIO1DIR &= ~((1uL << BUTTON1_BIT));` means everything _but_ this pin is output. `|= bit` is used to set a bit in an existing register to 1, `&= ~bit` is used to set one to 0.